# How to convert qdatetime into sql datetime and select from sql table in python?

Tags: sql, pyodbc, qdatetime

User choose the QDateTime and I need to write query in pyodbc which selects items in table which date are greater than choosen date.
How to convert it in sql datetime? And how to write this request?

Comment: Did my answer help you? I noticed that none of your previous questions have been marked with an answer. If you see an answer that has helped you, you can put closure to your question by marking it as accepted. I'd encourage you do that with your previous questions that have been answered.

Comment: @zedfoxus Ok, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert QDateTime variable (e.g. starttime) to a formatted string using something like this:

```
starttime.toString("YYYY-mm-dd");
```

Pass this to Python.

To convert that to python's native datetime, do this:

```
import datetime
starttime = datetime.datetime.strptime(data_you_got_from_QDateTime, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

That'll give you a Python datetime.datetime object to work with.

If you just want to use the data provided by QDateTime in a SQL query, you could do this:

```
import pyodbc

yourdate = date_received_from_QDateTime

cn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SQLSRV01;DATABASE=DATABASE;UID=USER;PWD=PASSWORD')
cursor = cn.cursor()

cursor.execute("select * from yourtable where yourfield > ?", yourdate)
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print row
```

That should give you reasonable information to tweak the codes above to get you the information. Since I am not aware how you are sending QDateTime to Python, I cannot comment on it.